# Django: how to run data migrations on every test case

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I have a two simple unit tests for django rest framework.

The second test always fails, because database is empty for it. 
I have a data migration, which intializes my data, but it isn't applied for the second test.

Here is the full code. Database sqlite.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import django
django.setup()
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework import status
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from . import models

class BaseTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'user'
        self.user = User.objects.create(username=self.username, password=self.username)
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.token.key)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.token.delete()
        self.user.delete()

class GMTOffsetsTestCase(BaseTestCase):    
    def test_get_all_offsets(self):
        url = reverse('offset-list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        # We have 37 timezones
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 37)    

class TimezonesTestCase(BaseTestCase):   
    def test_create(self):
        gmt_offset = models.GMTOffset.objects.all().first()
        data = {'name': 'From Test', 'city': 'Saint Petersburg', 'offset': str(gmt_offset.id)}
        url = reverse('timezone-list')
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

django 1.7.4, python 3.4

What could be wrong with these tests?

Should I change database engine?

Comment: Have you considered using a test database fixture?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, could you please explain it?